# How do I run a subdirectory on a separate server?

Tags: blog, iis7

I have a site, www.domain.com. I want to set up a blog which runs on a separate server than the main site, and have it available a the domain www.domain.com/blog.

How would I go about doing this? If it were blog.domain.com, then it would be easy, but with www.domain.com/blog I'm not so sure.

I'm using Windows Server 2008 / IIS 7.

Comment: I updated your title to better reflect your question.

Comment: @Mr. Flibble: out of curiosity, why don't you want to use `blog.domain.com` to host your blog?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with URL Rewrite module using "Reverse Proxy" kind of rule (when incoming request is handled/internally redirected to be processed by another back-end server), but for this you will also need an [Application Request Routing](http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting) to be installed. Unfortunately I have not dealt with AAR much and cannot really advise further. With Apache it is easier -- it is part of the default functionality (as long as you enable right module).

Keep in mind -- this will be **slower** than hosting the blog on the same server, as request has to travel to main server first, then to another (blog) server and back, and only then the response/page will be sent back to the user.

**UPDATE:**
Here is the article that describes how this can be done with details and illustrations (it is dated Nov 2009 but everything still should be the same or very similar): [Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/).

Comment: If you cannot/do not want to use AAR, but can install some software on your IIS 7 server, then you may also look at [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/ape/). _"Helicon Ape provides support for Apache .htacces and .htpasswd configuration files in Microsoft IIS. It literally implements Apache configuration model and nearly all Apache modules in a single IIS add-on, not only making IIS compatible with Apache, but also extending it’s functionality by a number of highly essential features."_

Comment: Thanks LazyOne. I tried out the procedure in 'Reverse Proxy with URL Rewrite v2 and Application Request Routing'.  It kind of works, but leaves a lot of things broken - image tags etc. I guess with a bit of work it could be usable.

Comment: You may want to create **Outbound** URL Rewrite rule that is applied to the headers or the content of an HTTP response (the bottom part of  URL Rewrite module interface) to fix such image URLs on blog pages. Just keep in mind that this sort of rewriting is MUCH slower compared to the incoming URL Rewriting rules (obviously, as you have to process whole page compared to just URL) which will add even more delay when serving such blog pages. This should work, although I have not used them myself (no reason).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. I just ran into the same type of thing because I wanted to run a Wordpress blog but my site was hosted on a shared Windows host. I ended up moving my site to Rackspace's cloud hosting so I had my own dedicated server and installed the Wordpress dependencies on Windows.