# Can I host www.example.com/subpage on different machine?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns

If I am the owner of www.example.com that is hosted on one machine, is it technically possible to host www.example.com/subpage on different machine, with different IP?

Comment: Related: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15570/how-do-i-run-a-subdirectory-on-a-separate-server

Comment: Agree, it's a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow one of the tutorials online for setting up mod_proxy:

http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies